# get all data from mysql query in zend 2

Tags: zend-framework2

```
$sql = "select * from users"; 
$statement1 = $db->query($sql);
$result = $statement1->execute()->current();
```

The above code returns the data from a single user.
How to get the data from all users?

Please help.

Comment: @tasmaniski I tried but that doesnt work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tasmaniski mentioned in the comment, you need to remove the current(), and $result becomes a "resulSet", which is readable by a foreach. Try this:

```
$sql = "select * from users"; 
$statement1 = $db->query($sql);
$results = $statement1->execute();
foreach($results as $result){
    var_dump($result);
}
```

More documentation here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html

Comment: I was looking for some function which can get me all data without using foreach. Anyway Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get all data like this:

```
$sql = "select * from users"; 
$statement = $db->query($sql);
$results = $statement->execute();
$rec = $results->getResource()
->fetchAll();
```

you can use `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` in fetchAll to get data in assoc format.